# How do I get rid of the outside values in this graph using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x = power_current_pd8_on['VDD-CL(V)'] 
y = power_current_pd8_on['CLK_IN(Hz)']
z = IDCLA_pd8_on

ax.scatter(x , y, z, c='r', marker='o')

ax.set_xlabel('VDD-CL(V)')
ax.set_ylabel('CLK_IN(Hz)')
ax.set_zlabel('ID-CL(A)')
ax.set_title('VDD-CL(V) vs CLK-IN(Hz) vs ID-CL(A)')
ax.set_xlim3d(left=.80, right=.9, auto = False)
ax.set_ylim3d(bottom=0, top=.4, auto = False)
#ax.set_zlim3d(0,1000)

plt.show()
```

I don't really understand what I am doing because I have limited the graph to a certain set of parameters and yet it is still not working. I have 6 graphs like this and yet all of hem are having the same problem. The graph is being limited to the parameter but there are points that are leaving the graph as which I have no idea how to fix.

[image: Example plot]

Comment: Please provide data which can be used to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always throw out the data you don't want to be plotted.

```py
...

x = power_current_pd8_on['VDD-CL(V)'] 
y = power_current_pd8_on['CLK_IN(Hz)']
z = IDCLA_pd8_on

keepers = (x <= 0.9) & (x >= 0.8) & (y >= 0.0) & (y <= 0.4)

ax.scatter(x[keepers], y[keepers], z[keepers], c='r', marker='o')

...
```

Comment: Hey I tried what you just did to omit the data points and it said that objects can not be broadcast to a single shape. I dont really understand what to do. I am sorry the data is confidential, so I wold not be allowed to share it

Comment: ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape'''

Comment: @fff It's hard to help without being able to reproduce your example. Try creating some toy data that isn't confidential but still causes your issue. For example, `x = np.array([0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95]); y = 0.1 * np.ones(4); z = 0.001 * np.ones(4)`.